# Append xml tag with contents in a file

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

xmlstarlet - appending value from file causes weird issues

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:foo="http://www.example.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.example.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</config>
```

append.txt

```
<mint>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <cronExp>0 0 /5 * * ?</cronExp>
    <syncDeletes>true</syncDeletes>
    <syncProperties>true</syncProperties>
    <repoKey>example</repoKey>
    <url>https:// example.com/bar</url>
    <socketTimeoutMillis>15000</socketTimeoutMillis>
    <enableEventReplication>true</enableEventReplication>
    <syncStatistics>false</syncStatistics>
</mint>
```

I want to append the contents of append.txt after `/config/foo:singers`

Tried -

1. `xml ed -a /config/foo:singers -t text -n mints -v $(cat append.txt) test.xml` - 
   Fails with `failed to load external entity "<enabled>true</enabled>"`
2. `xml ed -a /config/foo:singers -t text -n mints -v "$(cat append.txt)" test.xml`

   - This does kind of replaces the content but adds entity characters like `&lt`, `&gt` etc

What is the correct way to append contents from a file for a tag?

Answer (score 2):

For everyone else who will stumble upon here, this worked for me ->

```
xml ed -a /config/foo:singers -t text -n mints -v "$(cat append.txt)" test.xml | xmlstarlet unesc | xml fo
```

`xmlstarlet unesc` being important - http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139540960

Comment: "xmlstarlet unesc" is ok in your case. But if there are escaped entities like &amp; somewhere else in the xml then "xmsltart unesc" will affect those entities. What I do is using xmlstarlet just to insert a token in the position I want the new node created. And then first insert the node inmediatly after the token using sed: sed -i '/token/r append.xml' test.xml And second remove the token: sed -i 's/token$//' test.xml If there is a better solution I'd be happy to hear about it